# How to multiply a number that has been enter in the form of html and display with a number while using html

Tags: html

when we enter the number in the form of html it will automatically multiply by 20. how to show the the answer on next field while using html?

Comment: We can't help if you don't post your code.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is a markup language (used for structuring/organizing your data), not a programming language (used for calculations...etc). For calculations, you'll likely want to utilize JavaScript to retrieve the values from the HTML fields, do some calculations, then write the value to the next field. There are other options, but that's probably the best place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener.

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="t1" oninput="getElementById('t2').value = this.value * 20">
<input type="text" id="t2">
</form>
```